# How to setState from reactjs non component function of a class component

Tags: reactjs, node.js, peerjs, peer

This is my peer.js file code to setup peer

```
export const peer = new Peer(peerid, {
      path: "/myapp",
      host: "localhost",
      port: "9000"
    });
peer.on('connection', function (c) {
    setSomeData('ABCD')//This is from some functional or class component
}
```

In a peer.on listener, I want to setState of class/function component, i can use usecontext but it will rerender peer.js as well.
The purpose is that i want to add more listener to peer.js, and they will trigger particular states.